# AWS AppSync IAM DynamoDb Role

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I am trying to create a simple IAM role to have my AppSync service connect to my DynamoDb database, but because AppSync is in preview, IAM does not recognize AppSync as a service. How do I create an IAM role for to let AppSync have full access to DynamoDb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trusted relationships side looks something like this

**Example Trusted Relationships Doc**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The policy doc is basically the same as always

**Example Policy Doc**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are using a CloudFormation template, it might look like this

**Example CloudFormation Template**

```
  AppSyncRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "appsync.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: "appsync-policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "dynamodb:PutItem"
                  - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
                  - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
                  - "dynamodb:GetItem"
                  - "dynamodb:Query"
                  - "dynamodb:Scan"
                Resource: "*"
```